# prometheus.yml file does not update when on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, configuration, prometheus, amazon-ecs

I have a multi-container web service application with Docker. It's set up so that prometheus is supposed to read from the web service on the same container and scrape it. When I build the image locally and navigate to http:localhost:9090/config the prometheus.yml file matches what I want it to be when run on AWS ECS:

```
version: "3.2"

global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 1m
scrape_configs:
- job_name: prometheus
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:9090
- job_name: alienboard-web
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 10s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:5000
```

*Locally* everything works as expected, and prometheus is able to scrape the web server "alienboard-web" (it shows up in localhost:9090/targets). However, when I push the compiled image to AWS, it never seems to update the prometheus.yml file once it's on an ECS container instance. Here is how it looks from http:{aws-ecs-ip}:9090/config:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    scheme: http
    timeout: 10s
    api_version: v2
    static_configs:
    - targets: []
scrape_configs:
- job_name: prometheus
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:9090
```

**Why does it not update the file?** I will also attach my docker-compose, Dockerfile, and prometheus.yml files if that helps.

prometheus.yml:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:9090']
  - job_name: 'alienboard-web'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:5000']
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.2"

volumes:
  grafana-data:
    driver: local
  prometheus-data:
    driver: local

services:

  area51-tracker:
    build: ./
    container_name: alienboard-web
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PYTHONBUFFERED=1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - back-end

  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.8
    network_mode: bridge
    networks:
      - back-end

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana-oss:latest
    container_name: grafana
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - area51-tracker

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.38.0
    container_name: prometheus
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./etc/prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus-data:/prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    depends_on:
      - area51-tracker

networks:
  back-end:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.8

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /area51-tracker

COPY . .
COPY './prometheus.yml' '/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "application.py" ]
```

My project directory looks like this:

- area51-tracker

  - etc/prometheus

    - prometheus.yml

  application.py

Thank you!

Comment: It appears you have a local /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml file that you are mapping into the container when you run it locally. How are you doing this mapping when you deploy to ECS? What method are you even using to deploy to ECS?

Comment: @MarkB I push the image onto ECR and create a web-service to pull the latest image from there.  Does "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml" only map to the container locally? Could you let me know how I would map it when I deploy to ECS? Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: You are mapping a local host volume into the container at run time (via docker-compose). To map it into the container at build time, you would need to copy it into the image via the `Dockerfile`. You haven't shown a Dockerfile at all. If you are just download the `prom/prometheus:v2.38.0` image from DockerHub, and then turning around and pushing it to ECR, you aren't actually accomplishing anything there. You certainly aren't adding your config files to the image that way.

Comment: @MarkB Sorry about that. I've added the Dockerfile onto my original post. From my understanding, with COPY . . the prometheus.yml file should be added to the volume since all files should be copied? I was thinking that if the docker image is built into a container, the result should be the same if it were on a local container or one on AWS.

Comment: I also have to add that when I remove the line COPY './prometheus.yml' '/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml' it appears that the config file on AWS remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so for anyone who may stumble across this question -- I ultimately had to create a separate image with prom/prometheus as the base. I created a separate Dockerfile and prometheus.yml file in their own directory:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM prom/prometheus
ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
```

prometheus.yml file:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:9090']
  - job_name: 'alienboard-web'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['{aws-instance-ip}:5000']
```

I built a separate image from these files and pushed it to ECR in its own private directory. Then, I configured the task definition to have the prometheus container use the new image.

This is obviously just a workaround that fits my specific needs, so I'm still curious if anyone has a solution that doesn't involve re-building an image just to implement a configuration file. I'm still not sure why the build loads the configuration locally, but not on AWS.

Addendum: when I ssh'd into the container instance, I could see the prometheus.yml file was there (bin/etc/prometheus), but it simply wasn't being used.

Comment: No that's not a workaround for your specific needs, that's literally how you use Docker to do this sort of thing. You keep focusing on how it works locally and not on AWS, but you have this entire volume mapping thing in docker-compose locally that you don't have at all on AWS.

Comment: Okay, you're right. Sorry for the confusion!